# Does quicksort have a max?

Tags: quicksort

My quicksort code can only sort up to 999 numbers, is there a reason as to why, I've searched a lot but can't find a good answer, so I am really hoping someone can answer it properly.

Comment: There is no info about which library or which language you referring to.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Also check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Answer (score 1):

If the quicksort works for small arrays but fails with large arrays, it's most likely due to stack overflow. Stack overflow can be avoided by recursing on the smaller sub-partition, then looping back for the larger sub-partition.

The question should post the actual code in order to determine if this is the actual cause of the problem. Failing at exactly 1000 (or more) numbers would be unusual.